Have "ls" read many filepaths from a file
I frequently use the following idiom to find all files in the file tree starting the current directory, then submit the file paths to ls -lt so that they are shown newest-first:
$ find * -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lt | head -n 20

I was surprised that the most recent file was missing.  After some troubleshooting, I found the reason to be that xargs processes 322 items by default, and the most recent file was not among the 1st 322 filepaths.
I could sleuth further to adjust the 322 maximum, but since I won't always know how many I'll need, I searched for ways to have ls read filepaths from a text file.  That way, I can send the finded file paths to (say) ~/tmp/FilePaths.txt and have ls read them from there.
Is there a way to have ls do this?  Is there a limit to how many files it can chronologically sort for the purpose of ls -lt?  Specifically, I need to have
each entire line in ~/tmp/FilePaths.txt interpreted as filepath.
There would be more options for achieving this if I use sed to adorn each line with (say) double quotes to force the line to be interpreted as a single argument, e.g., ls $(cat ~/tmp/FilePaths.txt).  However, some filenames will contain double quotes.  I use Cygwin in a corporate Windows environment, so anything goes as far as filenames go.  As described in the comments, another reason this wouldn't work is because quotes are interpreted as part of the filename if filenames result from the expansion of $(cat ~/tmp/FilePaths.txt).

"xargs processes 322 items by default" -- it's probably not a fixed limit, more likely it depends on the lengths of the strings involved. There are limits to the total length of command line arguments (+ envvars), but I would expect them to be somewhat higher. How long are your filenames?

Also, wrt. "use sed to adorn each line with (say) double quotes to force the line to be interpreted as a single argument, e.g., ls $(cat ~/tmp/FilePaths)" -- it doesn't work like that. If you haven't, do try it. E.g. ls -l $(echo file.txt) vs. ls -l $(echo '"file.txt"' ) (and note that echo '"file.txt"' does print "file.txt"; the output doesn't include the single quotes). Now, if you wrap things in double-quotes and feed them to xargs (without -0 or -d), it will interpret the quotes.

anyway, the limits that xargs has probably depend highly on the implementation. If the one on cygwin has a particularly low limit, that's a bit unlucky

@ilkkachu: Sorry for the late reply.  For some reasons, I missed the notifications in my Inbox.  I don't understand the rationale for your echo file.txt or the variations with quotes. I was referring to quoting each line in file.txt.  Also, I didn't want to go the path of adjusting xarg limits because my needs with vary with each situation.

yes, you mentioned quoting each line of the file, and then using ls $(cat ~/tmp/FilePaths). That won't work. Which you can test with echo inside the command substitution instead of the cat and the file.

That's interesting.  If I bookend each line in Filepaths.txt with double quotes, then echo $(cat FilePaths.txt prints each line including the double quotes.  Not what I expect.  Is this behaviour defined by bash, i.e., when assembling a argument list for a command from the lines of a file?  In this case, the lines are from FilePaths.txt and the command for which the argument list is being assembled is echo.

Yes, quote processing is only done for the initial command, not for the results of expansions. Same goes for lots of other things in the shell syntax, e.g. var='&& date'; echo $var prints just && date, it does not run date and print the current time, even though echo && date would. The expansions are not just simple text replacement, which is good, because it makes it actually possible to process arbitrary values as data.

You can read the lines of a file into a Bash array with readarray -t arr < "$filename" (and How can we run a command stored in a variable? is remotely related because that's one use case where people always try to embed quotes in their data)

Wow.  Now I recall the subtleties of Bash.  Thanks.  I may one day resort to readarray, but to be honest, I usually look for quick-and-dirty exploitation of Bash by relying heavily on simple use cases and resorting to more neanderthal recourse before delving in to advanced Bash.  I don't use Bash enough for the non-basic things to stick, so it can be costly time-wise.

It might be easier to avoid using ls altogether.
GNU find can report on last modification time and report it in epoch seconds.  This makes it easy to sort the results.
So, for example
find * -type f -printf "%T@ %t %p\n"

The %T@ reports time in seconds; the %t reports it in human readable form, and the %p is the pathname.
We can then sort and head so we get
find * -type f -printf "%T@ %t %p\n" | sort -nr | head -20


Thanks, Stephen.  I found this to be what I wanted: find * -type f -printf "%TF %TT %s %p\n" | sort -r | head.  Here is an example of the output: 362140 aisstream-logger/ShpNm.csv. I marked yours as the answer.  In keeping with the question, however, would you be able to say that ls doesn't take input from a file?

@user2153235 I'm not aware of any option to ls that does this

I'm finding that find's -printf is very powerful, but also not something that one remembers (nor is it easy to type).  One can wrap the invocation in a function, but oftentimes, I want custom crafting of the find command.  I also use many machines, so that's another customization I would need to propagate and across machines and accounts.  So at least so far, it is a powerful tool for focused use in specific situations, but not easily used on a casual and routine basis.
